# Multivalued complex functions as differentiable manifolds

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, differential-geometry, reference-request

Could anyone point to some literature regarding the construction of multivalued functions as holomorphic functions on a differentiable manifold with complex structure? For example with the function $f(z) = \sqrt{z}$. One considers the sheets $F_1$ and $F_2$ respectively given by $f(z)$ and $-f(z)$. Taking as a branch for instance $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{ 0 \}$. Noticing that in $F_1$ if you let $arg(z) \to \pi$ you get the same result as in $F_2$ letting $arg(z) \to -\pi$. Then $\frac{F_1 \cup F_2}{\sim}$ under the equivalence relation that id entifies the upper side of $\Re(z)\leq 0$ in $F_1$ with the lower side of $\Re(z) \leq 0$ in $F_2$ and viceversa defines a topological structure given by the quotient topology. In this case it is the topology of the sphere. I have been told that there is a natural way of inducing a differentiable structure on this space. Does anyone know of a book or literature that treats this topic formally?
Thanks

Comment: You should look at some classic books on Riemann surfaces, like George Springer's.

Comment: thanks, I'll look into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a [Riemann surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_surface?wprov=sfti1#), in the case of functions of one variable.

You are incorrect about the result of stitching those two spaces together. The Riemann surface domain of $\sqrt{\cdot}$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}.$

In general, if $g:U\to\mathbb C$ is holomorphic, then the inverse of $g$ is not a defined, but it can be defined on a subset of the graph of $g,$ $$G_g=\{(z,g(z))\mid z\in U\}.$$ Specifically, $h: G_g$ defined as $(z,g(z))\mapsto z.$

Unfortunate, $h$ is only holomorphic at the points $(z,g(z))$ where $g'(z)\neq 0.$

So the best Riemann surface domain for $g^{-1}$ is the set $\{(z,g(z))\in G_g\mid g'(z)\neq0\}.$

The sphere is a Riemann surface, it just doesn't result as an inverse function of a function on a subset of the complex plane. Rather, spheres can be thought of as stitching together $\mathbb C\times\{1,2\}$ with $(z,1)$ and $(1/z,2)$ made equivalent, with $z\neq 0.$ This amounts to $S^2=\mathbb C\cup\{\infty\}.$

In general, if $R1,R_2$ are Riemann surfaces, we can define holomorphic functions $f:R_1\to R_2.$ If $R_1,R_2$ are spheres, the set of diffeomorphism $S^2\to S^2$ correspond to the Möbius transformations.

We can extend $z\mapsto z^2$ by sending $(z,n)\mapsto (z^2,n)$ for $n=1,2$ and show that equivalent points go to equivalent points. But the inverse is not holomorphic at zero or infinity.